# Edit pagination text in the get_the_posts_pagination function

Tags: filters, pagination

I want to edit the screen_reader_text in link-template.php  Can I do this in a theme so it wont get overwritten on update.  It seems a filter is the best option but I cant find documentation on what filter to use.

Here is the code I want to change from link-template.php:

```
    if ( $GLOBALS['wp_query']->max_num_pages > 1 ) {
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, array(
        'mid_size'           => 1,
        'prev_text'          => _x( 'Previous', 'previous set of posts' ),
        'next_text'          => _x( 'Next', 'next set of posts' ),
        'screen_reader_text' => __( 'Posts navigation' ),
    ) );
```

How can I change Posts navigation to something else, via functions or another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify `screen_reader_text` argument when invoking [the_posts_pagination()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_posts_pagination/) wrapper function in your theme files:

```
<?php the_posts_pagination( array(
    'mid_size'  => 2,
    'prev_text' => __( 'Back', 'textdomain' ),
    'next_text' => __( 'Onward', 'textdomain' ),
    'screen_reader_text' => __( 'Whatever', 'textdomain' ),
) ); ?>
```

Search for `the_posts_pagination` in your template files, and adjust texts as you wish.

[image]

Comment: This is a bad idea if you're using a theme from the repository or one bought commercially as the next time it's updated you will lose your customisations!

Comment: than you can use the child theme. this is where child themes shine.

Answer (score 2):

`__()` means that the text is being passed through the `gettext` filter, so you can get it there by adding something like this to your functions.php:

```
function change_my_text( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    if ( $translated_text === "Posts navigation" )
        $translated_text = "My fab new text";
    return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_my_text', 20, 3 );
```

Hope that helps